# Git rebase fails with conflicts, but there are no conflicts

Tags: git, rebase, tortoisegit, merge-conflict-resolution

I tried to do a `rebase` on code that I had committed but not pushed, because I had heard that there were some changes in the origin that might affect what I was working on. Here's what I get:

```
$ git rebase origin/thor-develop
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: PH-2127: F193: SYO for Signed in User
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       js/angular/localization/StoreListCtrl.js
M       templates/default_site/site_embed.group/html_header.html
<stdin>:17: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:73: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:77: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:78: trailing whitespace.
                            $scope.address_dropdown = addressStore.getTop($scope.my_occasion, 3);
<stdin>:79: trailing whitespace.

warning: squelched 16 whitespace errors
warning: 21 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging templates/default_site/site_embed.group/html_header.html
Auto-merging js/angular/localization/StoreListCtrl.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in js/angular/localization/StoreListCtrl.js
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 PH-2127: F193: SYO for Signed in User

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

We use Tortoise Git as a front-end editor, so I went into the Resolve tool. It usually shows differences, which are of course OK, and conflicts, which are not. It shows me absolutely no conflicts in the file referenced (StoreListCtrl.js). There are obviously differences, but no conflicts at all. What does this mean, and how do I fix it so I can complete the rebase and eventually merge my code?

Comment: Careful with this. It's always a good idea to verify that your rebase worked. My usual solution here would be to compare the results with the head of the branch before rebasing (there should be no differences unless you changed patches to account for upstream changes, and hopefully those are simple enough that you can easily verify them as correct). Currently my environment seems to be bugged and git is breaking out of git rebase similar to the OP. If I `rebase --continue` though and compare later my autosquash fixups are lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible the resolve tool fixed the conflicts for you automatically. It's happened to me (and confused me) before. In this case, you can probably go straight to `git rebase --continue`.

The full checklist is:

- if `git status` shows any un-staged changes:

  - if those files have the chevrons `<<<` `>>>` marking conflicts:

    - fix the conflicts and save the files
  - now stage all un-staged changes with `git add`: this marks the conflicts as resolved
- now any conflicts are resolved and marked: use `git rebase --continue`

Comment: That's what seems to have happened. Save me from too-smart software.

Comment: TortoiseGit does not call `git rebase --continue`. It has UI to resolve conflicts and you click Continue button to run `git commit` and cherry-pick the next commit.

Comment: I didn't say it had already continued the rebase, but that it had resolved the conflicts.